# Series High School difficulty

Tags: sequences-and-series

Hi I have this problem which for some small detail I have not been able to fully answer.

The problem is: 
Given f(r) = $(2r+1)^3$, simplify $f(r) - f(r-1)$. Hence find $$\sum_{r=1}^{n}{r^2}$$

I have so far managed to come to the conclusions that:

$$f(r)- f(r-1) = 24r^2 + 2$$ and
$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}{(2r+1)^3-(2r-1)^3} = (2r + 1)^3 -1 $$

I am somehow doing some sort of mistake in the last part of the problem. Would appreciate help... thanks :)

Comment: See [Faulhaber's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula#Examples).

Answer (score 0):

$$f(r)- f(r-1) = 24r^2 + 2$$
$$r^2 = (f(r)- f(r-1) - 2)/24 $$

$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}{r^2} = \sum_{r=1}^{n}{(f(r)- f(r-1) - 2)/24} = (\sum_{r=1}^{n}{f(r)}- \sum_{r=1}^{n}{f(r-1)} - \sum_{r=1}^{n}{2)/24}$$
$$=(f(n)-f(0)-2n)/24$$

Note that you don't have to calculate the first two terms explicitly as most of them cancel out.

I assume you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks @mathlove, edited the mistake